# Get the ticket from KDC(centos7) in my windows but still cannot reach the web URL

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, centos7, mit-kerberos, kdc

I am new to `Hadoop` and I made a  `Hadoop cluster` with `3 centos machine` in my `VMware`, and I also `kerberosing` the cluster, it works fine in the `VMware`, I can reach the URL by `FireFox in CenotOS machine`

However, when I try to reach the page outside the `VMware(in my windows machine)` [it always shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zqv20.png)

1. I can ping each other by `IP` or `hostname`(I have set the hosts file)
2. I have got the ticket from `KDC` in my `windows machine by MIT Kerberos`, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlTM.png) and when I type `klist` in my `windows cmd`, it showed the ticket.
3. I have set the `firefox` as suggested(as in `centos` I can reach the
   page.)
4. what else should i set?

help please!

[the ticket i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSlTM.png)

this is my krb5.ini and krb5.conf in my windows and centos machine

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 renewable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = HADOOP.COM 

[realms]
HADOOP.COM = {
  kdc = master:88
  admin_server = master:749
}

[domain_realm]
master = HADOOP.COM
slave1 = HADOOP.COM
slave2 = HADOOP.COM
```

Comment: *"I have set the firefox as suggested"* -- what does that mean? did do change the Firefox configuration to enable GSSAPI library *(the Java/Linux way to handle Kerberos)* instead of SSPI library which is the default on Windows *(the Microsoft way to handle Kerberos inside Active Directory)*??

Comment: Thx at first , and the problem was solved, "I have set the firefox as suggested" means I change 2 value in firefox's "about:config" page 1.network.auth.use-sspi : false  2.network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris : my KDC's hostname.

Comment: When using the browser, you would need a service ticket for the 'Web Server'. Did you get one? The screenshot suggests a TGT only.

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris must list the actual service (web server) not the KDC